# What is happening to my colorbar when I open Illustrator?

Tags: cmyk, rgb, color-conversion, cs3

I usually create figures using something like Matlab or Python; then I use Illustrator for final touch-ups and things.  Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with the colorbars when I open my figures in CS3 (ancient, I know...)

My colormaps come from colorbrewer2.org.  For example, I'm trying to use a divergent, 11-class scheme expressed in RGB values.  It's a simple red-yellow-blue scheme that looks quite nice with my data.  Unfortunately, when I open my figure in Illustrator, the colorbar is a wreck:

[image: Messed-up colorbar as seen in the Illustrator window]

As you can probably tell, I don't *really* know what I'm doing in Illustrator!  I only use it to create simple schematics or make small changes to figures.  What's weird is that the colors in my figure look fine; it's just the colorbar that is messed up.  How can I fix my colorbar?  Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: try go to View->Proof setup and choose sRGB... (I am on CS6, so probably you have other options)

Comment: Open the file in Acrobat rather than Illustrator (which may or may not work) and check to see if the bar is okay there.

Comment: @Ilan, As you suggested, I went to View -> Proof Setup and sRGB (IEC61966-2.1), and it didn't change the colorbar.  I tried a few other options randomly (including Mac RGB, Windows RGB, and Monitor RGB).  Unfortunately my colorbar didn't change.

Comment: @Scott, the colorbar looks fine in Acrobat.  It's only messed up when I open it in illustrator.

Comment: Are you sure that the source image was RBG? Have you tried CMYK?
http://imgur.com/a/82yDa